# Parsing JSON with @

Tags: javascript, json

At the end of this question is standard JSON returned from an ebay api call.

I have no problem parsing most of it e.g. to get title, time left etc I'm using:

```
var items = root.findItemsByKeywordsResponse[0].searchResult[0].item || [];

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
    var item = items[i];
    var title = item.title;
    var timeLeft= item.sellingStatus[0].timeLeft;
}
```

But I can't figure out how to get currency, I've tried

```
var currencyID= item.sellingStatus[0].currentPrice[0].@currencyId;
```

But console tells me illegal character with arrow pointing at the @ symbol - what's the correct way to parse that?

```
{
   "findItemsByKeywordsResponse":[
      {
         "ack":[
            "Success"
         ],
         "version":[
            "1.12.0"
         ],
         "timestamp":[
            "2014-03-26T18:29:40.583Z"
         ],
         "searchResult":[
            {
               "@count":"100",
               "item":[
                  {
                     "itemId":[
                        "151258132867"
                     ],
                     "title":[
                        "Apple iPhone 4 - clean esn - Black (Verizon) Smartphone"
                     ],
                     "globalId":[
                        "EBAY-US"
                     ],
                     "primaryCategory":[
                        {
                           "categoryId":[
                              "9355"
                           ],
                           "categoryName":[
                              "Cell Phones & Smartphones"
                           ]
                        }
                     ],
                     "galleryURL":[
                        "http:\/\/thumbs4.ebaystatic.com\/m\/mGwHzpyvkph9-nU12sCspxw\/140.jpg"
                     ],
                     "viewItemURL":[
                        "http:\/\/www.ebay.com\/itm\/Apple-iPhone-4-clean-esn-Black-Verizon-Smartphone-\/151258132867?pt=Cell_Phones"
                     ],
                     "productId":[
                        {
                           "@type":"ReferenceID",
                           "__value__":"101787954"
                        }
                     ],
                     "paymentMethod":[
                        "PayPal"
                     ],
                     "autoPay":[
                        "false"
                     ],
                     "postalCode":[
                        "93905"
                     ],
                     "location":[
                        "Salinas,CA,USA"
                     ],
                     "country":[
                        "US"
                     ],
                     "shippingInfo":[
                        {
                           "shippingServiceCost":[
                              {
                                 "@currencyId":"USD",
                                 "__value__":"0.0"
                              }
                           ],
                           "shippingType":[
                              "Free"
                           ],
                           "shipToLocations":[
                              "US"
                           ],
                           "expeditedShipping":[
                              "true"
                           ],
                           "oneDayShippingAvailable":[
                              "false"
                           ],
                           "handlingTime":[
                              "2"
                           ]
                        }
                     ],
                     "sellingStatus":[
                        {
                           "currentPrice":[
                              {
                                 "@currencyId":"USD",
                                 "__value__":"96.0"
                              }
                           ],
                           "convertedCurrentPrice":[
                              {
                                 "@currencyId":"USD",
                                 "__value__":"96.0"
                              }
                           ],
                           "bidCount":[
                              "17"
                           ],
                           "sellingState":[
                              "Active"
                           ],
                           "timeLeft":[
                              "P0DT0H0M11S"
                           ]
                        }
                     ],
                     "listingInfo":[
                        {
                           "bestOfferEnabled":[
                              "false"
                           ],
                           "buyItNowAvailable":[
                              "false"
                           ],
                           "startTime":[
                              "2014-03-19T18:29:51.000Z"
                           ],
                           "endTime":[
                              "2014-03-26T18:29:51.000Z"
                           ],
                           "listingType":[
                              "Auction"
                           ],
                           "gift":[
                              "false"
                           ]
                        }
                     ],
                     "returnsAccepted":[
                        "false"
                     ],
                     "condition":[
                        {
                           "conditionId":[
                              "3000"
                           ],
                           "conditionDisplayName":[
                              "Used"
                           ]
                        }
                     ],
                     "isMultiVariationListing":[
                        "false"
                     ],
                     "topRatedListing":[
                        "false"
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "itemId":[
                        "360810145746"
                     ],
                     "title":[
                        "U Apple iPhone 3GS - 8GB - Black (FACTORY UNLOCKED) Smartphone (C)"
                     ],
                     "globalId":[
                        "EBAY-US"
                     ],
                     "subtitle":[
                        "****USA SELLER*****FAST SHIPPING*****TOP SELLER****"
                     ],
                     "primaryCategory":[
                        {
                           "categoryId":[
                              "9355"
                           ],
                           "categoryName":[
                              "Cell Phones & Smartphones"
                           ]
                        }
                     ],
                     "galleryURL":[
                        "http:\/\/thumbs3.ebaystatic.com\/m\/mQGXy5hucEtqk6inUKFu67g\/140.jpg"
                     ],
                     "viewItemURL":[
                        "http:\/\/www.ebay.com\/itm\/U-Apple-iPhone-3GS-8GB-Black-FACTORY-UNLOCKED-Smartphone-C-\/360810145746?pt=Cell_Phones"
                     ],
                     "productId":[
                        {
                           "@type":"ReferenceID",
                           "__value__":"99984545"
                        }
                     ],
                     "paymentMethod":[
                        "PayPal"
                     ],
                     "autoPay":[
                        "true"
                     ],
                     "postalCode":[
                        "10001"
                     ],
                     "location":[
                        "New York,NY,USA"
                     ],
                     "country":[
                        "US"
                     ],
                     "shippingInfo":[
                        {
                           "shippingServiceCost":[
                              {
                                 "@currencyId":"USD",
                                 "__value__":"0.0"
                              }
                           ],
                           "shippingType":[
                              "Free"
                           ],
                           "shipToLocations":[
                              "US",
                              "CA",
                              "GB",
                              "AU",
                              "FR",
                              "HK",
                              "MT",
                              "IE",
                              "IL",
                              "NZ",
                              "PH",
                              "SG"
                           ],
                           "expeditedShipping":[
                              "true"
                           ],
                           "oneDayShippingAvailable":[
                              "false"
                           ],
                           "handlingTime":[
                              "1"
                           ]
                        }
                     ],
                     "sellingStatus":[
                        {
                           "currentPrice":[
                              {
                                 "@currencyId":"USD",
                                 "__value__":"84.95"
                              }
                           ],
                           "convertedCurrentPrice":[
                              {
                                 "@currencyId":"USD",
                                 "__value__":"84.95"
                              }
                           ],
                           "sellingState":[
                              "Active"
                           ],
                           "timeLeft":[
                              "P12DT0H9M11S"
                           ]
                        }
                     ],
                     "listingInfo":[
                        {
                           "bestOfferEnabled":[
                              "false"
                           ],
                           "buyItNowAvailable":[
                              "false"
                           ],
                           "startTime":[
                              "2013-12-08T18:33:51.000Z"
                           ],
                           "endTime":[
                              "2014-04-07T18:38:51.000Z"
                           ],
                           "listingType":[
                              "StoreInventory"
                           ],
                           "gift":[
                              "false"
                           ]
                        }
                     ],
                     "returnsAccepted":[
                        "true"
                     ],
                     "condition":[
                        {
                           "conditionId":[
                              "3000"
                           ],
                           "conditionDisplayName":[
                              "Used"
                           ]
                        }
                     ],
                     "isMultiVariationListing":[
                        "false"
                     ],
                     "discountPriceInfo":[
                        {
                           "originalRetailPrice":[
                              {
                                 "@currencyId":"USD",
                                 "__value__":"449.0"
                              }
                           ],
                           "pricingTreatment":[
                              "STP"
                           ],
                           "soldOnEbay":[
                              "false"
                           ],
                           "soldOffEbay":[
                              "false"
                           ]
                        }
                     ],
                     "topRatedListing":[
                        "true"
                     ]
                  }
```

Comment: You could use `var currencyID= item.sellingStatus[0].currentPrice[0]['@currencyId'];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to access the property using a string with bracket notation

```
var currencyID= item.sellingStatus[0].currentPrice[0]["@currencyId"];
```

You need to do this anytime a property does not start with a alpha, **_**, or **$** character

> [Dot notation Property Accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Dot_notation)
>
> get = object.property;
>
> object.property = set;
>
> property must be a valid JavaScript identifier, i.e. a sequence of alphanumerical characters, also including the underscore ("_") and dollar sign ("$"), that cannot start with a number. For example, object.$1 is valid, while object.1 is not.

Comment: Many thanks, will accept when I can... is there a reason they would format it this way as opposed to a normal string ie just currencyId?

Comment: No I cannot think of a reason they do that, it might be some internal structure they use. The devs of their api are probably the only ones that know.